# how to strech image on one side in swiftUI, like a .9 file in Android?

Tags: swiftui

i have an image that i want to strech only it's height to fit different content, how do i do that in swiftUI? right now it looks like this

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 130) {
                Text("Title")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)

                Text("text")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)

                Text("padding")
            }
            .padding(.vertical)

            Spacer()

            Image("rightTag")
                .resizable(capInsets: .init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0), resizingMode: .stretch)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(maxWidth: 20)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: screen.width - 60)
            .padding(.leading)
            .background(.white)
            .cornerRadius(20)
        }
    }
}
```

how can i stretch its height to fit this outer frame? ragular resizable and stuff can't get it done.
any helped would be wonderful! Thanks!
sry i didn't make myself clear earllier.

Comment: it would be great if you'd demo what you expect.

Comment: It is not about Image, it just layout issue. Provide your code as code, not a screenshot, so it can be fixed.

Comment: i've provided my code, please check it out, thanks! @Asperi

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible approach. However as I see now you'd rather need to stretch not the entire original image, but only middle of it, so in real project it would be needed to make your image tri-part and apply below stretching approach only to middle (square) part.

Approach uses asynchronous state update, so works in Live Preview / Simulator / RealDevice. (Tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var textHeigh: CGFloat = .zero
    var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 130) {
                Text("Title")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)

                Text("text")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)

                Text("padding")
            }
            .padding(.vertical)
            .alignmentGuide(.top, computeValue: { d in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.textHeigh = d.height // !! detectable height of left side text
                }
                return d[.top]
            })

            Spacer()

            Image("rightTag")
                .resizable()
                .frame(maxWidth: 20, maxHeight: max(60, textHeigh)) // 60 just for default
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: screen.width - 60)
            .padding(.leading)
            .background(Color.white)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for helping! but it didn't seem to work, i've updated my question to make my goal clearer, please check it out.